# Servlet pdf download button creation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a servlet where I want when a user press one button, it will generate a dynamic pdf (according to user given data) and download it to user's c:/ location. Can anybody help me how to do that ?

Comment: @Poindexter, actually, I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: You know how to generate the PDF and you are trying to know how to download it to the user? Downloading a file from a browser requires user choose the location where to store the file.

Comment: @DavidOlivánUbieto, OK. Can you help how to do that means downloading in user specified location ?

Comment: Not possible, security issues. Browser will ask user the folder where to store the file, except when a previous folder is remembered by the browser and downloads automatically to this location. There are some ways, but using signed applets and so on, not servlets (aka regular HTML).

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand your comment. You only need to response from the servlet with the file using the right MIME type and the browser will ask automatically the user where to store the file. Returning a file from a servlet if a very basic question, googling you can get http://www.coderanch.com/t/355331/Servlets/java/Return-File-Servlet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What exactly is unclear to you? How to write an html form? How to get parameters from HttpServletRequest? Or how to generate pdf and download to user?

```
<form action="yourServlet">
 <input type="text" name="sometxt"/>
 <input type="secret" name="passwd"/>
 <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Then, you can retrieve it in your getXXX method like

```
final String text  = request.getParameter("sometxt");
final String rawPassword = request.getParameter("secret");
```

If you  need to render a pdf, you should look on Apache PdfBox.

And finally, if you in trouble with downloading file to user:

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
InputStream in = ... // depends where you store your file 
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
while(in.read(buffer, 0, 4096) != -1)
   out.write(buffer, 0, 4096);
in.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
```

And don't forget about handilng IOException, which i missed in simpicity purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a good example of a Java servlet to download a file: http://www.dzone.com/snippets/example-file-download-servlet.

Note that there is no need to ask the user where to download the file, that is handled by the browser download mechanism.

There's also some useful information here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-download-file-from-website-java-jsp/.